# Flickering image after loading in winforms at timer tick event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, image, timer

My question is the following:
I have a timer and each 1 ms i want to load an image and display it in a picture box in win forms
The first images work very fine however from some point the images start loading hard.
Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Regards and thank you for your time :)

```
   private string path = "";
    private int index = 0;
    private void fileSourceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fullPath = ofd.FileName;
            string fileName = ofd.SafeFileName;

            path = fullPath.Replace(fileName, "");

            MessageBox.Show("Path for file source has been selected");
        }
    }

    private const string IMAGENAME = "TestImage";
    Bitmap b;
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string currentImage = IMAGENAME + index.ToString() + ".bmp";
            index++;
            b = new Bitmap(path + "\\" + currentImage);

            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb.Image = b;
        }
        catch { };

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string currentImage = IMAGENAME + index.ToString() + ".bmp";
            index += 1;
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(path + "\\" + currentImage);

            pb.Image = b;
        }
        catch { };
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            index -= 1;
            string currentImage = IMAGENAME + index.ToString() + ".bmp";
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(path + "\\" + currentImage);
            pb.Image = b;
        }
        catch { };
    }
```

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what you did(Post your code)

Comment: Use a 1 ms timer is *very* unrealistic, the human eye can't possibly distinguish a thousand images per second.  It already turns into a blur at 20 images/sec.  This starts to grind down when your program starts using way too much memory, forgetting to call the Dispose() method on the old image is a standard mistake.

Comment: the 1 ms timer means that the change between the frames is so fast we cannot tell they are pictures loaded since it looks like a movie

Comment: @MMp131316 yes, and what Hans is trying to say is most movies run with a frame every 41.6667 ms (24 fps), not every 1 ms (1000 fps). You are falling in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) explain what you want your program to do, we can then give you the correct way to do that goal.

Comment: when i select a path, I want my program to start showing all the pictures from the selected folder in a picture box. The pictures should be displayed very fast s.t. for someone that is looking at the picture box it would seem that it is a movie playing

Answer (score 0):

Play with DoubleBuffered property first.

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ is very slow and even when using double buffering then it's still slow.
I would suggest you to find an alternative as there isn't really a way to fix the "flickering".

However there is one thing, the way you're actually loading the images in the tick handle is pretty cpu consuming.

I would suggest you load all the required image's bytes into a collection of some sort, ex. an array.
Then simply create the bitmap from the image bytes.

Besides you're not even disposing the current image, which you should before allocating new memory for the next image.

Comment: if I put a b.dispose() after pb.Source = b i don't see anything

Comment: Then dispose the image _after_ showing it: `timer_Tick(...) { if (pb.Image != null) pb.Image.Dispose(); } ...`

Comment: the dispose helps :)! but doesn't solve the whole issue, after 3000 frames with the timer interval set on 75 I still get some flickering